# How to display a zero in a cell when the count is zero? (MS Access 2010 Query)

Tags: sql, ms-access

I've looked over some of the related questions but could not find a solution specific to my problem. I've created a cross tab query using MS Access on a table that has the fields department name and created on (date field). I've grouped the department names in the first column and have a count of id's to show the total number of items created in this week. Here is my SQL Query.

```
TRANSFORM Count([Issue Mgt].ID) AS CountOfID
SELECT [Issue Mgt].[Deparment Name], Count([Issue Mgt].ID) AS [Total Of ID]
FROM [Issue Mgt]
WHERE (((Format([Created],"ww"))=DatePart("ww",Date())))
GROUP BY [Issue Mgt].[Deparment Name]
PIVOT Format([Created],"ww");
```

What I'm struggling to do is display a zero in a cell where the count is zero. Any help is appreciated and pardon me if my question is poorly structured as its my first ever post here!

Answer (score 1):

As the count will return a null value you will have to wrap it in an NZ function like this

```
NZ(Count([Issue Mgt].ID),0)
```

Its like a mini "If, Then" statement, the first part is what you are checking and the second part is what to return if the first part is null

Comment: I thought COUNT always returns a value. Is that not so in MS Access?

Comment: It would normally but this is a crosstab query so on the rows/columns where there is no data it will have a null value hence the need for the NZ function. My memory is kicking up something about having to add 0 at the end but I dont have a copy of access around to try

Comment: I see. Which instance of COUNT then do you mean the NZ function should be added to, the one after TRANSFORM or the one in the SELECT clause? Sorry if that looks like a silly question, my knowledge of MS Access is next to nil. Nevertheless I think adding NZ in the SELECT clause would change nothing.

Comment: From memory it will be on the transform one

Comment: That is an important detail, I think. And since it is *your* answer and it is *your* memory, then it is *you* who should updated the former. :)

Comment: Hi thanks for all your help. Managed to find the solution.

NZ(Count([Issue Mgt].ID))+0

This adds a zero whenever there is a null value in a column cell of a row which has a value.

Comment: I have no idea why `NZ(Count([Issue Mgt].ID))+0` would be preferred to `NZ(Count([Issue Mgt].ID,0)`. Please explain. That is, when you omit the second argument for Nz(), you are taking your chances as to what you'll get, and by adding 0 you're implicitly coercing it to a numeric value. But if you just supply the 0, it will do that for you, no?

Answer (score 1):

Hi thanks for all your help. Managed to find the solution. NZ(Count([Issue Mgt].ID))+0 This adds a zero whenever there is a null value in a column cell of a row which has a value.

Comment: This is a comment I posted above: I have no idea why NZ(Count([Issue Mgt].ID))+0 would be preferred to NZ(Count([Issue Mgt].ID,0). Please explain. That is, when you omit the second argument for Nz(), you are taking your chances as to what you'll get, and by adding 0 you're implicitly coercing it to a numeric value. But if you just supply the 0, it will do that for you, no?

Answer (score 1):

The specific was not explained.  I just had to keep trying things out until I got it right.  So for anyone else who would like to see the actual answer, here it is:

The first line needed to be changed in the SQL view

TRANSFORM NZ(Count([Issue Mgt].ID),0)